# Git Action showing Permission Denied: I have an error when pushing my code under yarn generate which causes check failure

Tags: reactjs, github

**Git Action showing Permission Denied: I have an error when pushing my code under yarn generate which causes check failure**
Run .github/scripts/check-generate.sh
/home/runner/work/_temp/f8e35a4a-aca8-4505-bb51-f91ca590d9bd.sh: line 1: .github/scripts/check-generate.sh: **Permission denied**
Error: Process completed with exit code 126.

Answer (score 3):

**Git Action Showing Permission Denied**
I solved the issue with:

```bash
git update-index --chmod=+x ./.github/scripts/YOUR_SCRIPT.sh
```

More info at:

- https://github.community/t/action-showing-permission-denied/134957.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
git update-index --chmod=+x ./.github/scripts/check-generate.sh
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

1. Set execution permission on the file:

   **Linux or macOS:**

   ```
   chmod +x script.sh
   ```

   **Windows:**

   ```
   git update-index --chmod=+x script.sh
   ```
2. Push changes to remote repository:

   ```
    git add script.sh
    git commit -m '...'
    git push
   ```

Source: [*How to Fix GitHub Action "Permission Denied" Error When Executing a File?*](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-github-action-permission-denied-error-when-executing-a-file)